# Array out of range mql4

Tags: mql4, mt4

I am trying to add indicator code, which works perfectly on its own, to an EA MQL4 source. While everything compiles just fine, the terminal tab shows the above error.

Both errors occuring relate to *tick[i+k]*.

```
double ticks[];
double tick[];

int init() {

   ArrayResize(ticks,TotalBars); ArraySetAsSeries(ticks,true);
   ArrayResize(tick,TotalBars); ArraySetAsSeries(tick,true);
   return(0);
}

int start() {

for (i=TotalBars-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
         avg = tick[i];
            for (k=1; k<AveragePeriod && tick[i+k]!=0; k++) avg += tick[i+k];
                                                                avg /= k;
         ....
```

I want to prevent *iCustom* calls. What could be the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: `tick[i+k]` sometimes does not exist because i can be number of bars you have (and array is already resized to that size) and k can be large (e.g. if AveragePeriod = 13 then k is in (1;12)). you should think of this scenario and choose what to do. I would suggest to start looping over i from TotalBars-1-AveragePeriod)

Comment: Yes, now I see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste an indicator code directlt to an EA cause the problem, that is due to the the fact that in an indicator file arrays handle automatically.
The bug code be fixed by some minor change in the code. For instance, you could check the size of the array tick then perform the below code or instead of using k<AveragePeriod, use k < MathMin(AveragePeriod - i , ArraySize(tick) - i ).
That would solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you're iterating from `i = TotalBars - 1` down to `i = 0`. However, when you use `tick[i+k]` inside the loop, it's possible that `i + k` exceeds the array size, causing the "out of range" error.

```
int start() {
int maxIndex = TotalBars - 1; // Adjust this if necessary

for (int i = maxIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i + AveragePeriod >= TotalBars) {
        // Ensure i + k stays within array bounds
        continue;
    }

    double avg = tick[i];
    int k;
    for (k = 1; k < AveragePeriod && i + k < TotalBars && tick[i + k] != 0; k++) {
        avg += tick[i + k];
    }
    
    if (k > 0) {
        avg /= k;
        // ...
    }
}
return 0;
}
```